# Currency TextBox accepting numbers only in universal store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am working on a Universal Windows App. I have a `TextBox` that I would like to only accept numbers. And, also, format the `TextBox` as U.S. currency (without the $ sign - just commas and decimal)

I already have a working code below in my `TextChanged`. Also, commented for easier read. I was just wondering, since I am very new to this, if I am doing this right? Is there a better way of accomplishing the same? It feels very strange to me that MS do not include a baked in way for something as simple as this.

Thanks

```
 private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do not apply if textbox is empty - needed to avoid exceptions
        if (textBox.Text.Length == 0) { return; }
        decimal charInput;
        string value = textBox.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "").TrimStart('0');                       
        // Make sure to only accept numbers as input          
        if (decimal.TryParse(value, out charInput))
        {
            charInput /= 100;
            //Unsub the event so we don't enter a loop
            textBox.TextChanged -= textBox_TextChanged;
            //Format numbers as currency
            textBox.Text = string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N}", charInput);
            textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
            textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);
        }
        else {
            // Remove last character if NOT a number
            textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Remove((textBox.Text.Length - 1));
            // force cursor to the end of text to avoid random movements                
            textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Text.Length;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set up *InputScope* of your textbox control?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no specific class out there for that. However, below is an MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644(v=vs.100).aspx) that shows a class driven by the TextBox that worked fine for me in the past.

Hope this helps!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644(v=vs.100).aspx